# Jetpack Compose Arc/Circular Progress Bar Animation (How to restart animation)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-progressbar, compose-recomposition, jetpack-compose-animation

How do I create a Arc Progress bar animation like this

[image: animated progress]

Currently I've already used Canvas to draw an arc and added animations to the progress bar using animateFloatAsState API. But second pic is not my expected.

[[image: My current implementation]]

[image: My current implementation]

```
// e.g. oldScore = 100f  newScore = 350f
// Suppose 250 points are into one level

@Composable
fun ArcProgressbar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    oldScore: Float,
    newScore: Float,
    level: String,
    startAngle: Float = 120f,
    limitAngle: Float = 300f,
    thickness: Dp = 8.dp
) {

    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(oldScore) }

    val sweepAngle = animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = (value / 250) * limitAngle,  // convert the value to angle
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000
        )
    )

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(1500)
        value = newScore
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.45f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            onDraw = {
                // Background Arc
                drawArc(
                    color = Gray100,
                    startAngle = startAngle,
                    sweepAngle = limitAngle,
                    useCenter = false,
                    style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                    size = Size(size.width, size.height)
                )

                // Foreground Arc
                drawArc(
                    color = Green500,
                    startAngle = startAngle,
                    sweepAngle = sweepAngle.value,
                    useCenter = false,
                    style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                    size = Size(size.width, size.height)
                )
            }
        )
        
        Text(
            text = level,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.125f)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .offset(y = (-10).dp),
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 82.sp
        )

        Text(
            text = "LEVEL",
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    }
}
```

How can I animate from start again if progress percentage over 100%, just like the one in the gif. Does anybody got some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I made another answer since the first one doesn't really look like your posted GIF, I don't want to delete it though since you already accepted it and for future  readers, some people might see it and may find it useful. Its a full source code that you can simply copy and paste  (preferably on a separate .kt file) without any hassle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first answer doesn't feel like doing any justice since it's far from the gif you posted which shows what you want.

So here's another one that closely resembles it. However, I feel like this implementation is not very efficient in terms of calling sequences of animations, but in terms of `re-composition` I incorporated some optimization strategy called [deferred reading](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-debugging-recomposition-bfcf4a6f8d37), making sure only the composables that observes the values will be the only parts that will be re-composed. I left a `Log` statement in the parent progress composable to verify it, the `ArcProgressbar` is not updating unnecessarily when the progress is animating.

```
Log.e("ArcProgressBar", "Recomposed")
```

Full source code that you can copy-and-paste (*preferably on a separate file*) without any issues.

```
val maxProgressPerLevel = 200 // you can change this to any max value that you want
val progressLimit = 300f

fun calculate(
    score: Float,
    level: Int,
) : Float {
    return (abs(score - (maxProgressPerLevel * level)) / maxProgressPerLevel) * progressLimit
}

@Composable
fun ArcProgressbar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    score: Float
) {

    Log.e("ArcProgressBar", "Recomposed")

    var level by remember {
        mutableStateOf(score.toInt() / maxProgressPerLevel)
    }

    var targetAnimatedValue = calculate(score, level)
    val progressAnimate = remember { Animatable(targetAnimatedValue) }
    val scoreAnimate = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LaunchedEffect(level, score) {

        if (score > 0f) {

            // animate progress
            coroutineScope.launch {
                progressAnimate.animateTo(
                    targetValue = targetAnimatedValue,
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000
                    )
                ) {
                    if (value >= progressLimit) {

                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            level++
                            progressAnimate.snapTo(0f)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // animate score
            coroutineScope.launch {

                if (scoreAnimate.value > score) {
                    scoreAnimate.snapTo(0f)
                }

                scoreAnimate.animateTo(
                    targetValue = score,
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 1000
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box {
            PointsProgress(
                progress = {
                    progressAnimate.value // deferred read of progress
                }
            )

            CollectorLevel(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                level = {
                    level + 1 // deferred read of level
                }
            )
        }

        CollectorScore(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
            score = {
                scoreAnimate.value // deferred read of score
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CollectorScore(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    score: () -> Float
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "Collector Score",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )

        Text(
            text = "${score().toInt()} PTS",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 40.sp
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CollectorLevel(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    level: () -> Int
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 16.dp),
            text = level().toString(),
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 82.sp
        )

        Text(
            text = "LEVEL",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun BoxScope.PointsProgress(
    progress: () -> Float
) {

    val start = 120f
    val end = 300f
    val thickness = 8.dp

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.45f)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .align(Alignment.Center),
        onDraw = {
            // Background Arc
            drawArc(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                startAngle = start,
                sweepAngle = end,
                useCenter = false,
                style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                size = Size(size.width, size.height)
            )

            // Foreground Arc
            drawArc(
                color = Color(0xFF3db39f),
                startAngle = start,
                sweepAngle = progress(),
                useCenter = false,
                style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                size = Size(size.width, size.height)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Sample usage:

```
@Composable
fun PrizeProgressScreen() {

    var score by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    var scoreInput by remember {
        mutableStateOf("0")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xFF6b4cba)),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 16.dp),
            text = "Progress for every level up: $maxProgressPerLevel",
            color = Color.LightGray,
            fontSize = 16.sp
        )

        ArcProgressbar(
            score = score,
        )

        Button(onClick = {
            score += scoreInput.toFloat()
        }) {
            Text("Add Score")
        }

        TextField(
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            value = scoreInput,
            onValueChange = {
                scoreInput = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for such attentive sample!

Answer (score 2):

I made some changes in your code to utilize `Animatable` so we always `snap` to the beginning before animating to our `target` value. We also eliminated the computation here since we just want to fill the entire progress every time the score updates, in our case to **300** (`limitAngle`) and used the `newScore` state as a `key` in the `LaunchedEffect` to trigger the animation every time it increments. Don't mind the `+30` increments, its just an arbitrary value that you can change without affecting the animation.

```
@Composable
fun ArcProgressbar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    newScore: Float,
    level: String,
    startAngle : Float = 120f,
    limitAngle: Float = 300f,
    thickness: Dp = 8.dp
) {

    val animateValue = remember { Animatable(0f) }

    LaunchedEffect(newScore) {
        if (newScore > 0f) {
            animateValue.snapTo(0f)
            delay(10)
            animateValue.animateTo(
                targetValue = limitAngle,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 1000
                )
            )
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.45f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            onDraw = {
                // Background Arc
                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Gray,
                    startAngle = startAngle,
                    sweepAngle = limitAngle,
                    useCenter = false,
                    style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                    size = Size(size.width, size.height)
                )

                // Foreground Arc
                drawArc(
                    color = Color.Green,
                    startAngle = startAngle,
                    sweepAngle = animateValue.value,
                    useCenter = false,
                    style = Stroke(thickness.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square),
                    size = Size(size.width, size.height)
                )
            }
        )

        Column {
            Text(
                text = level,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.125f)
                    .offset(y = (-10).dp),
                color = Color.Gray,
                fontSize = 82.sp
            )

            Text(
                text = "LEVEL",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                color = Color.Gray,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )

            Text(
                text = "Score ( $newScore ) ",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                color = Color.Gray,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
@Composable
fun ScoreGenerator() {

    var newScore by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            newScore += 30f
        }) {
            Text("Add Score + 30")
        }

        ArcProgressbar(
            newScore = newScore,
            level = ""
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't describe question well, I fix the description a little bit. What I wonder is if keep `+30` and over 100% how can I animate like from 0% again? For example if 200% I expect the green indicator will make a circle twice. (0%-100%) * 2

Comment: I see, I'm not really good at animations and there must be a better way, but I made some changes in your code utilizing `Animatable` and edited my answer.

Comment: No problem!, glad to help!, I would also advice revisiting, I'm actually expecting someone better than me at this to provide a more efficient way of what you want to achieve here, you could also check the official docs for other animations, but anyways, thanks for accepting the answer!